# Installing Chromium on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, amazon-ec2, chromium, amazon-linux

I am trying to install Chromium (or Chrome, whichever) on an Amazon Linux machine.

I have tried many steps, to no avail. Here is what I have tried:

#### Simple Yum Install

```
yum install epel       # worked
yum install chromium
```

generated error message:

> ```
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libgnome-keyring.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libXss.so.1()(64bit)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libcanberra-gtk2(x86-64)
> Error: Package: chromium-31.0.1650.63-2.el6.x86_64 (chromium-el6)
>            Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
> ```

#### Yum install of specific RPM package

I tried downloading a Chrome RPM, both [the latest stable version](http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64//google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.119-1.x86_64.rpm) as well as a specific version, and then running

```
yum install google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.119-1.x86_64.rpm
```

It yielded the same error message

#### Manual procedure

Downloaded binary from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/532015/

Running it generated the error message

> error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I ran

```
yum install libXcursor
yum install libXfixes     # because chrome was then complaining about that library
yum install libXdamage    # and subsequently that one
```

which all worked.

However, then Chrome started complaining about a `libcups` library :

> error while loading shared libraries: libcups.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

`libcups` wasn't found by yum, and it seems that this is because it is a 32 bit library. Some page recommended to install `ia32-libs` as a solution, but running `yum install ia32-libs` showed that it was already installed.

I couldn't get past that point.

#### Other

- I also tried steps mentioned [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44855#p192908), but that didn't work
- some pages point to using `dpkg`, but that command doesn't exist on Amazon Linux apparently
- `apt` neither

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's so that you can have a full development environment on AWS, I recommend using Ubuntu instead. AWS Linux really doesn't want to be graphical (I've gone down that path and ended up just as unhappy as you).

Comment: @kdgregory thanks for the comment. I am actually not looking for being graphical, but for using chrome in headless mode. I am actually using AWS only as a place to test what I am doing on Linux instead of Mac

Comment: sudo yum install libX11 Gconf2 fontconfig

Comment: @palafox, thanks, I'll try that. Have you actually done it on AWS ?

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew maybe this can help you https://gist.github.com/palafoxernesto/38efba25b845ba3f34b96d008c2415f5

Answer (score 35):

None of these answers , work, and none of them actually solves problem for amazon linux,

To really solve the problem if you are using EC2 instance or any other server where you are running Amazon linux, you should follow the below steps .

1. Enable and install Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux by running the command

   ```
   sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
   ```
2. Post installing all the extra packages successfully, Install chromimum as usual

   ```
   sudo yum install -y chromium
   ```

Once you do that Chromium will have all required such as libatk* libgdk* etc ...

You should be able to easily launch Chromium

The missed out packages that you are looking here, are actually not missedout they are kind of default you just have to enable them , this is well documented in AWS documentation .

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I won't have time to dedicate to test that right now, but it sounds relevant, and hopefully it will help other people. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Great answer, this worked beautifully for me.

Comment: worked for me as well, this is awesome

Comment: works on Amazon Linux 2, but not on t2.micro or t2.small because not enough memory. works on t2.medium.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly for me on an Amazon Linux 2 docker base image, but it did bloat the resulting image by about 500MB.

Comment: won't work on Amazon Linux 2023, because amazon-linux-extras does not exist on that image. https://superuser.com/questions/1777045/amazon-linux-extras-command-not-found

Answer (score 12):

In order to get headless chrome working on Lambda, I deployed an identical AMI as an EC2 instance (currently amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2). After installing chrome, the usual litany of missing dependencies begins.

Reference: https://medium.com/mockingbot/run-puppeteer-chrome-headless-on-ec2-amazon-linux-ami-6c9c6a17bee6

Navigate to the folder containing the chrome executable and use ldd to check for missing dependencies:

```
$ ldd chrome | grep not
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => not found
libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
libcairo.so.2 => not found
libXcursor.so.1 => not found
libXdamage.so.1 => not found
libXfixes.so.3 => not found
libcups.so.2 => not found
libXss.so.1 => not found
libXrandr.so.2 => not found
libgconf-2.so.4 => not found
libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
libgtk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

Install the following:

```
$ sudo yum install cups-libs dbus-glib libXrandr libXcursor libXinerama cairo cairo-gobject pango
```

Check again:

```
$ ldd chrome | grep not
libXss.so.1 => not found
libgconf-2.so.4 => not found
libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
libgtk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk-3.so.0 => not found
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
```

We need to grab these dependencies from a maddeningly large set of RPMs:

```
# Install ATK from CentOS 7
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-2.22.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/at-spi2-atk-2.22.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/at-spi2-core-2.22.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
# Install GTK from fedora 20
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/g/GConf2-3.2.6-7.fc20.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libXScrnSaver-1.2.2-6.fc20.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libxkbcommon-0.3.1-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libwayland-client-1.2.0-3.fc20.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/l/libwayland-cursor-1.2.0-3.fc20.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/g/gtk3-3.10.4-1.fc20.x86_64.rpm
# Install Gdk-Pixbuf from fedora 16
$ sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.0-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

That should resolve all the dependencies and chrome should be able to run, finally!!

Comment: Thank you for this. Recently ran for ElasticBeanstalk. Created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chimmelb/6342504893b2b9fce0f4a8efd096ae60) to run all these as a config file rather than being on the machine.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was getting crazy how to find the missing packages...

Comment: This worked with `Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.5.6` in Elastic Beanstalk. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use chromium for headless testing via AWS Ubuntu launched through CodeBuild. I found I had to update node and install a set of chromium dependencies.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Installing nodejs (which will include node and npm)"
echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs  
echo "Installing chromium dependencies"
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Amazon Linux 2022, there are several packages missing, running `ldd chrome | grep not` in the Chromium directory yields:

```
    libnss3.so => not found
    libnssutil3.so => not found
    libsmime3.so => not found
    libnspr4.so => not found
    libgbm.so.1 => not found
```

These packages aren't available for Amazon Linux 2022 *but* you can find them on https://rhel.pkgs.org/8 which works because this distribution is based on RHEL 8.

So these should fix it:

```
sudo dnf install http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/8/x86_64/release/okay-release-1-1.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install nss
sudo dnf install mesa-libgbm
```

Comment: i got failed to launch error and this command sudo dnf install mesa-libgbm help me, thanks