# Facing chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127 while using Headless chrome browser with docker & python 3.7 on AWS ec2

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

This is not a duplicate of other questions & I have tried the existing answers as well. On AWS ec2 I have created a docker container in which I am trying to open headless chrome. The docker file is

```
FROM python:3
# Install Chrome for Selenium
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -o /chrome.deb
RUN dpkg -i /chrome.deb || apt-get install -yf
RUN rm /chrome.deb
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d chromedriver
RUN chmod +x /chromedriver/chromedriver
ENV PATH="/chromedriver:${PATH}"
RUN echo 'logging path'
RUN echo "${PATH}"
```

The code which I am using to open browser is:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
```

The error which on ec2 is:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /chromedriver/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I have tried 
 [Installing Chromium on Amazon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480143/installing-chromium-on-amazon-linux/49678986) and other stackoverflow answers as well but unable to solve it.
Google-chrome version - Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100
driver version - 2.38
selenium - 3.141.0
The OS of AWS AMI is linux and not ubuntu thuscommand ldd chrome | grep not would help. Even though I have fixed that issue as well, still getting error. When logged the path of chromedriver it's logged as below

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chromedriver_binary:/chromedriver:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323099/webdriverexception-message-service-chromedriver-unexpectedly-exited-status-co)

Comment: Also check this https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/1245

Comment: @mchawre tried it as well. current output is ldd chrome | grep not
./chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0)
./chrome: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libatspi.so.0)

Comment: @AlwaysanewComer have you resolved the issue?

Comment: you can try apt-get install xvfb

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error which was fixed by installing xvfb, this is required because you are running a headless session of chrome. Try doing `apt-get install xvfb`